# run time error for std::bad_alloc g++

Tags: c++

The following code gives me bad alloc with g++ : 
   `std::bad_alloc what(): "St9bad_alloc"`. I'm not able to understand the reason as this is the first element I'm adding to the `vector` so no memory limit issue should be there

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyCity {
  string name;
  std::vector<pair<string,double> > neighbours;
public:
  MyCity(string s)
  {
    name =s;
    // neighbours.clear();
  }
  MyCity(string s, string s1, double d)
  {
    name = s;
    neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(s1,d));
  }
};

class MyState {
  vector<MyCity*> cities;
  string name;
public:
  MyState() { }
  MyState(string s)
  {
    name =s;
  }
  bool add_city(string name, string neigh, double d)
  {
    MyCity* c = new MyCity(name,neigh,d);
    cities.push_back(c);
  }
  bool add_city(string name)
  {
    MyCity* c = new MyCity(name);
    cities.push_back(c);
    return true;
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyState* ss;
  ss->add_city("agra");
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious mistake is that `ss` is not pointing to a `MyState` object. It points to an undetermined memory location, to which you shouldn't be writing. You could bypass that problem entirely by not using a pointer in the first place:

```
MyState ss;
ss.add_city("agra");
```

Also note that `MyState` handles pointers to dynamically allocated objects. You have to be careful with that: currently you have a memory leak. When you fix it, you will then have to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator (or disable copying and assignment). Or you may decide that you don't need to hold dynamically allocated objects at all, which would greatly simplify things:

```
class MyState 
{
  std::vector<MyCity> cities; // look, no pointers
  ....
  bool add_city(const string& name, const string& neigh, double d)
  {
    cities.push_back(MyCity(name,neigh,d)); // can use emplace_back in C++11
    return true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code. The problem being that you create a pointer `ss` but never initialize it to point to anything. That means its value is undefined and will be completely random.

Either declare it as a non-pointer (my recommendation), or allocate memory for it with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize ss pointer like that.

```
MyState* ss = new MyState();
/*
*
* Your Code
* 
*/
delete ss;
```

Comment: and then try to remember to delete it later on